# MVC 5 DIV acting a widget (using Url.Action) to post form values

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, forms, http-post, url.action

I'm in a bit of a quandary at the moment, to set the scene there is a dropdown list at the top of the page followed by a bunch of "clickable" DIV elements and I've made them clickable by wrapping an Action around them.

However, the issue is that none of them POST values to the controller so i cannnot read the contents of the dropdownlist. Further reading suggests it is because I am using Action which do not normally post values.

However, all examples I have found so far seem to include having a "submit" input type button but I would prefer if the DIV element can act as a button but also post values.

I guess the question is, before I ditch what I'm trying to do - is such a thing possible? Any help appreciated!

Within Form (DropDown)

```
      <div class="row">

            <span class="label label-primary">Reporting Period </span> @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ReportQuarterID, new SelectList(Model.ReportingQuarters, "Id", "Name", new { @class = "dropdown" }), new { @id = "ddlReportingQuarter" })

        </div>
```

Within Form (Clickable Div)

```
           <a href="@Url.Action("QuarterlySpendBySite", "Reports")">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 hvr-grow">
                    <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                        <div class="ibox-title y-bgc-s1">
                            <h5>Quarterly Spend By Site</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ibox-content no-padding">



                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
```

Within Controller

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult QuarterlySpendBySite()
    {

        return View(new Test.Models.TestReporting_BL());
    }
```

Above routine is ignored, if I remove HTTPPost it will work fine but if I try Request.Form["ddlReportingQuarter"] - it returns null.

Comment: Request.Form["ddlReportingQuarter"] will alwasy return null unless you submit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#ActionLinkId').click(function() {

     var selectedVal=$("#ddlReportingQuarter option:selected").val();

        $.post({
            url: $('#ActionLinkId').attr('href'),
            type: 'post',
            data: {selectVal: selectedVal}
            success: function(data) {

            }

        });

        // prevent the default action, If not it'll redirect
        return false;
       });
      }
</script>
```

And in controller make this change.

```
 [HttpPost]
       public ActionResult QuarterlySpendBySite(string selectVal)
       {

            return View(new Test.Models.TestReporting_BL());
       }
```

Comment: Thanks but there are multiple actions each "widget" or DIV so to speak represents a separate Action, but they all need to reference the selected value within the drop down list.

Comment: Do you want to send the value using post method or can you send it through url??

Comment: Let me know as there are other ways, do you want to redirect to other page or just call the controller?

Comment: Hmm no sorry, cant get it to hook up to div - I've added code snippets in case what I was saying was not making sense

Comment: add id property <a id="ActionLinkId"  href="@Url.Action("QuarterlySpendBySite", "Reports")">

Comment: Nearly! Get an error message in console: POST http://localhost:58893/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)

Comment: make the above change in controller.

Comment: Thanks, added but still same error; looks like it is not reading the href attribute properly..

Comment: Yup copied and pasted exactly: <a id="ActionLinkId" href="@Url.Action("QuarterlySpendBySite", "Reports")">

Element Result looks like:
<a id="ActionLinkId" href="/Reports/QuarterlySpendBySite">
         ...
</a>

Comment: try this url: $('#ActionLinkId').attr('href')  instead of $(this).attr('href') i've edited the jquery function check it. If doesn't work show me the complete code what you have added so far.

Comment: If I replaced it with $.ajax I receive the error message.. POST http://localhost:58893/Reports/QuarterlySpendBySite 500 (Internal Server Error) ... so getting the URL right now but receiving 500 error... (oh and I tried replace this with "ActionLinkId" earlier!)

Comment: Yay got it working! Thanks! The internal 500 error was due to an ambiguous name so the ajax change fixed it. (from $.post to $.ajax - all I had to do then was to remove any non httppost reference to QuarterlySpendBySite). You're a star :)